# start omxplayer with matchbox window manager

Tags: raspbian, boot, script, omxplayer

I have a RPI 3 with Raspbian Jessie, set up to boot in cli mode, autologin with user pi. I have installed matchbox window manager because it's lighter than lxde and I use only chromium and omxplayer.
I added to .bashrc:

```
if [ -z "${SSH_TTY}" ]; then
  xinit ~/startup.sh
fi
```

startup.sh:

```
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank
unclutter -idle 0 &
matchbox-window-manager -use_cursor no -use_titlebar no &
/var/test/player.py
```

player.py:

```
...
os.system("omxplayer /var/test/video.mp4")
...
```

All scripts running fine, omxplayer starts, but i don't have video to my screen, the player runs somwhere in the background.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Later Edit: If I remove "xinit" from  "xinit ~/startup.sh" it works. But I don't what that, I use xinit to open also a chromium instance. Somewhere within x server and omxplayer is something strange...

Comment: I'm doing something similar, and used "-o hdmi" to the omxplayer command. I did have to disable the OpenGL video driver. Does omxplayer work properly if called from a terminal?

Comment: Yes, omxplayer works fine if called from terminal. OpenGL is disabled. Also try with "-o hdmi", no luck...

Comment: When you write "the player runs somwhere in the background", do you mean you're hearing audio, or that you just see the process? Is there more than one omxplayer process?

Comment: I just see the process running, 2 procesess (omxplayer, omxplayer.bin). No sound or video.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your GPU memory split is at least 128MB and that OpenGL is disabled.

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Advanced Options,Memory Split

Advanced Options,GL Driver

Comment: Hi CoderMike,
Yes, gpu mem split is 128, also try with 192. GL Driver is disabled.
If I run the script manually from console (logged as user pi), omxplayer start just fine, it's no problem. The problem is on startup.